# Manipulating and comparing dates with GregorianCalendar and can't get the code to work properly

Tags: java, android, java-time

I'm struggling to find the error in my code here. paytotal is coming out 0 when it should have a number.

`firstDayOfPaycheck` is the date Oct. 23rd 2020.

`lastDayOfPaycheck` is the date Nov. 6 2020.

My Simple date format `sdf` is "MMM dd, yyyy".

string `dateInQuestion` passed into runPayroll is "Oct. 31, 2020" which came originally from the same sdf as above.

I'm new to java and haven't dealt with manipulating the calendar like this. It feels like the code below should work.

```
 private void runPayroll(String dateInQuestion, long payForTask){   
     c.setTime(firstDayOfPaycheck);
        
        //loop through days of paycheck. number from time.compareTo(time2) is negative while time is before time2 
        while(c.getTime().compareTo(lastDayOfPaycheck)<=0){

            if(dateInQuestion != null) {

                Date questionDate = sdf.parse(dateInQuestion, new ParsePosition(0));
                if (c.getTime().compareTo(questionDate) == 0) {
                    payTotal += payForTask;
                }
            }
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
} //ran inside the query to get the total pay

private void buildPayrollDash(){
    String strPayrollAmt = "$" + payTotal;


    String startDate = sdf.format(firstDayOfPaycheck);
    String trimmedStart = startDate.split(",")[0]; //cuts out the year in the date
    String endDate = sdf.format(lastDayOfPaycheck);
    String trimmedEnd = endDate.split(",")[0];
    int holdBack = sharedPreferences.getInt("payroll holdback", 7);
    c.setTime(lastDayOfPaycheck);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, holdBack);
    String payDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    String trimmedPaydate = payDate.split(",")[0];

    tvPayrollTimefame.setText("Pay from " + trimmedStart + " - " + trimmedEnd);
    tvPayrollAmount.setText(strPayrollAmt + " due " + trimmedPaydate);
```

Comment: Hello mate. The Calendar class is not recommended for usage anymore since it contains some design flaws. The recommended tools now are in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package such as LocalDateTime. If you're looking for measuring between two dates, check out the Period class.

Comment: You can find a Java Tutorial on the usage of Period [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html). That should be usable to more concisely calculate the number of days your code currently tries to find.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll switch over to that

Comment: Since you’re switching over to the much better API, it probably doesn’t matter now, but you should have [created a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As your question stands, I can’t tell what has gone wrong, and I frankly doubt that anyone can. So please do for your next questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm struggling to find the error in my code here.

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, or their relatives.

> `firstDayOfPaycheck` is the date Oct. 23rd 2020.

Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent a date without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate firstDayOfPayPeriod = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.OCTOBER , 23 ) ;
```

> `lastDayOfPaycheck` is the date Nov. 6 2020.

You'll find date-time handling much easier if you define your spans-of-time using the Half-Open approach. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So instead of focusing on the last day of the pay period, focus on the first day of the following period.

```
LocalDate firstDayOfSuccessivePayPeriod = LocalDate.of( 2020 , 11 , 7 ) ;
```

Tip: You can represent the date range of the pay period as a [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) object if you add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your Java project.

> My Simple date format `sdf` is "MMM dd, yyyy".

You should not be mixing business logic with localization code. Custom formatting of date-times should only be done for presentation to the user.

When exchanging date-time values textually as data, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For a date-only value, the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD. The *java.time* use ISO 8601 formats by default, so no need to specify any formatting pattern.

> string `dateInQuestion` passed into `runPayroll` is "Oct. 31, 2020" which came originally from the same sdf as above.

```
LocalDate dateInQuestion = LocalDate.parse( "2020-10-31" ) ;
```

If you must accommodate an input of formatted date string rather than standard ISO 8601 format, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

And rather than check for valid data later, check your inputs early in your code. “Fail fast” is the saying.

```
try
{
    LocalDate dateInQuestion = LocalDate.parse( "2020-10-31" );
}
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    // … Handle faulty input.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> I'm new to java and haven't dealt with manipulating the calendar like this. It feels like the code below should work.

Your code will be much simpler when using *java.time*. For one thing, the *java.time* classes offer convenient `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual` methods, so no need for clumsy `compareTo` calls.

```
LocalDate firstDayOfPayPeriod = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.OCTOBER , 23 );
LocalDate firstDayOfSuccessivePayPeriod = LocalDate.of( 2020 , 11 , 7 );

String input = "2020-10-31";
LocalDate dateInQuestion = null;
try
{
    dateInQuestion = LocalDate.parse( input );
}
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    // Handle faulty input.
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Validate dates.
Objects.requireNonNull( firstDayOfPayPeriod );
Objects.requireNonNull( firstDayOfSuccessivePayPeriod );
Objects.requireNonNull( dateInQuestion );
if ( ! firstDayOfPayPeriod.isBefore( firstDayOfSuccessivePayPeriod ) )
{
    throw new IllegalStateException( "…" );
}
if ( dateInQuestion.isBefore( firstDayOfPayPeriod ) )
{
    throw new IllegalStateException( "…" );
}
if ( ! dateInQuestion.isBefore( firstDayOfSuccessivePayPeriod ) )
{
    throw new IllegalStateException( "…" );
}


long payPerDay = 100;
long partialPay = 0;

LocalDate localDate = firstDayOfPayPeriod;
while ( localDate.isBefore( firstDayOfSuccessivePayPeriod ) )
{
    if ( localDate.isBefore( dateInQuestion ) )
    {
        partialPay = ( partialPay + payPerDay );
    }

    // Set up the next loop.
    // Notice that java.time uses immutable objects. So we generate a new object based on another’s values rather than alter (mutate) the original.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 ); // Increment to next date.
}

System.out.println( "Partial pay earned from firstDayOfPayPeriod " + firstDayOfPayPeriod + " to dateInQuestion " + dateInQuestion + " is " + partialPay );
```

See this [code run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2NLQrO).

> Partial pay earned from firstDayOfPayPeriod 2020-10-23 to dateInQuestion 2020-10-31 is 800

With more experience in programming Java, you may want to do this kind of work using streams. See [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)).

By the way, if you want to skip weekends, add something like this:

```
Set< DayOfWeek > weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
…
if ( weekend.contains( localDate.getDayOfWeek() ) ) { … }
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: switching over to this API solved my problem. Thanks Basil